# Delay all next elements in Webflux after first one is emitted

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have in my app a reactive endpoint that returns a flux from database that never ends unless communication from the front stops. What I want to accomplish is to load first element as soon as possible and then throttle next elements by adding some delay. What I accomplished so far is to delay all elements that first one is loaded after same delay as every next one.

```
    var connection = Mono.fromFuture(
                    () -> dataCollector.getDataFromCassandra((CassandraExposureRetrieveRequest) command.getBody()))
            .delayElement(Duration.ofMillis(delayExposure))
            .repeat()
            .share();
```

Does anyone know if there is a rather simple way to delay second, third etc. element from the flux ?

Kind regards,
Bartek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your elements come from a Mono that is repeated multiple times, you can achieve this my prepending your Flux with a single non-delayed database call Mono:

```java
var singleCall = Mono.fromFuture(
        () -> dataCollector.getDataFromCassandra((CassandraExposureRetrieveRequest) command.getBody()));
var connection = singleCall
        .concatWith(singleCall.delayElement(Duration.ofMillis(delayExposure))
                .repeat())
        .share();
```

**Edit:** By request, here is a solution if the data source is a Flux instead of a repeated Mono:

### Flux solution

To split the first element from all other elements, I use [`Flux.switchOnFirst(BiFunction)`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#switchOnFirst-java.util.function.BiFunction-) to modify the Flux when the first signal is received. The `BiFunction` receives the first signal and the original Flux and maps it to the modified Flux. In this case, I map the original Flux to a Flux with its first element removed, then throttling all remaining elements , and lastly the first element is re-added at the start from the signal.

```java
var connection = originalFlux.switchOnFirst((signal, flux) -> {
    if (signal.hasValue()) {
        return flux.skip(1)
                .delaySequence(Duration.ofMillis(delayExposure))
                .startWith(signal.get());
    }
    return flux;
});
```

Note that the BiFunction receives the first *signal*, which can also be an onError or an onComplete. To handle these, the Flux is only modified if the Signal has a value, else the Flux is returned unmodified.

This solution works for any operation that has to modify all the elements except the first one, for that replace the `.delaySequence` line with your desired operation(s).

Comment: Thanks a lot Patrick - this does the trick :) do you maybe know or anyone else if is there a way to adapt this to that did not origins from mono ? :D

Comment: @Icarium Sure! I've added a Flux solution to the original answer.